# Анимация появления текстового символа

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

У меня есть svg изображение буквы `А` которая составлена из трех элементов:
двух параллелограммов и прямоугольника - перекладины.

Необходимо сделать последовательную анимацию появления сначала левой наклонной части буквы, затем правой части и в конце анимации появление перекладины.

```html
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="600" width="800" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <g fill="#008080">
    <polygon id="right"  
    points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
 <polygon  id="left"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
   </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55609857/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант, где `opacity` считается по дельта времени между кадрами.

```js
let left = document.querySelector('#left')
let right = document.querySelector('#right')
let rect1 = document.querySelector('#rect1')
let time = 3000; // время анимации 
let delay = 1000; // задержка перед анимацией

// dt - кол-во миллисекунд с начала анимации
function animate(dt) { 
 let v = dt - delay;  
 opacity(left, v/time*3);     
 opacity(right, v/time*3 - 1);
 opacity(rect1, v/time*3 - 2);
 dt < time + delay + 50 && requestAnimationFrame(animate)
} 

function opacity(el, v) {
 v = Math.min(1, Math.max(v, 0)); // приводим к диапазону 0-1
 el.setAttribute('opacity', v)
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="175" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <g fill="#008080">
    <polygon id="right" opacity="0" points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
    <polygon id="left" opacity="0" points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" opacity="0" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
   </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Отлично, но на мой вкус, немного побыстрее бы сделал анимацию, но у каждого свой вкус и фломастеры

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там я специально вынес задержку и время в переменные

Answer (score 4):

Вот такой вот эффект c `background-image` и `keyframes`.

Для этого группа фигур из оригинала была переделана в маску для прямоугольника.

```html
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
   <style>  
    svg {
      height:160px;
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Pr8tfnT.png);
      background-position: 0px 111px;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-size: 100%;
      animation: water 10s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes water {
      100% {
        background-position: 2000px 0px;
      }
    }
   </style>   
   <mask id="mask" fill="black">
    <rect fill="white" width="600" height="800"/>
    <polygon id="right" points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
    <polygon id="left"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
   </mask>
   
   <rect fill="white" width="600" height="800" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

В ходе выполнения было замечено что у оригинала `svg` `viewbox` и `width`, `height` перепутаны...

Comment: Развиваешься во всех направлениях? js, d3 надоели :) ? Хорошо получилось, красиво. Будешь делать новый вариант, этот не стирай/ Всё же я жду вариант на нативном JS, повторяющим анимацию из первых ответов.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я без проблем могу и на js, но тут не для него задача чесслово

Comment: это учебный топик, кому-то обязательно будет полезно, сделай пожалуйста, если оч. противно, не делай, я пойму :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да не то чтобы, если никто не предложит - сделаю

Answer (score 3):

### SVG решение

Все элементы анимации в начале невидимы `fill-opacity="0"`

Анимация появления одного элемента:

```
<animate
      id="an_left"
      attributeName="fill-opacity"
      begin="1s"
      from="0"
      to="1"
      dur="0.3s"
      fill="freeze"/>
```

Последовательность выполнения анимаций достигается цепочкой условиё в атрибуте `begin="an_left.end"`

Такая запись означает что анимация правого прямоугольника начнется только после окончания анимации левого многоугольника

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  
    <polygon id="right" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" 
    points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55">
    <animate
      id="an_right"
   attributeName="fill-opacity"
   begin="an_left.end"
   from="0"
   to="1"
   dur="0.3s"
   fill="freeze"/>
 </polygon>   

 <polygon  id="left" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51">
   <animate
   id="an_left"
   attributeName="fill-opacity"
   begin="0.2s"
   from="0"
   to="1"
   dur="0.3s"
   fill="freeze"/>
  </polygon> 

    <rect x="120" y="320" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"> 
     <animate
  id="an_rect"
  attributeName="fill-opacity"
  from="0"
  to="1"
  begin="an_right.end"
  dur="0.3s"
  fill="freeze"/>
 </rect> 
</svg>
</div>
```

### CSS решение

```css
.container {
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
#left,#right,  #rect1 {
fill-opacity:0;
fill:#008080;

}
#left {
animation:anLeft  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@keyframes anLeft {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
 
  }
} 
#right {
animation:anRight  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes anRight {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
  }
}  

#rect1 {
animation:anRect  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay:0.7s;
}

@keyframes anRect {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  
    <polygon id="right"  
    points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
 <polygon  id="left"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
</svg>
</div>
```

### Второй вариант

```css
.container {
 width:35%;
 height:35%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <g fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" >
       <polygon  id="left" transform="rotate(72 306 200)"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"> 
         <animateTransform
           attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate"
           values="72 306 200;0 306 200"
           begin="svg1.click"
           dur="0.5s"
           fill="freeze" />  
  <animate id="an_op1"
      attributeName="fill-opacity"
      from="0" to="1"
      begin="svg1.click"
      dur="0.5s"
      fill="freeze" /> 
 </polygon>  
     <polygon id="right"  transform="rotate(-69 457.5 200)" 
        points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55">
    <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        values="-69 457.5 200;0 457.5 200"
        begin="an_op1.end"
        dur="0.5s"
        fill="freeze" />  
  <animate id="an_op2"
     attributeName="fill-opacity"
     from="0" to="1"
     begin="an_op1.end"
     dur="0.5s"
     fill="freeze" />
 </polygon>   
    <rect id="rect1"  x="800" y="320"    width="270" height="120"> 
         <animate attributeName="x"
            from="800" to="120"
            begin="an_op2.end"
            dur="0.5s"
            fill="freeze" /> 
      <animate id="an_op3"
        attributeName="fill-opacity"
        from="0" to="1"
        begin="an_op2.end"
        dur="0.5s"
        fill="freeze" />
 </rect>     
   </g>  
     <text x="0" y="80" font-size="50" fill="purple">Click me</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612661/7394871)@Alexandr_TT

Comment: Хорошо получилось!

Answer (score 3):

```css
.letter {
  width:200px;height:auto;
  stroke-width:2.5;
  stroke:#000;
  fill:none;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 24;
}
.animateFirst { animation: 0.5s animateFirst ease-in forwards; }
.animateSecond { animation: 0.2s 0.45s animateSecond ease-out forwards; }

@keyframes animateFirst {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 24 24; }
}
@keyframes animateSecond {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 6 24; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="letter" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
  <polygon class="animateFirst" points="1,11.5 6,0 11,11.5" />
  <polygon class="animateSecond" points="3,6.5 9,6.5" />  
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55615000/7394871):@web-tiki